# How to: creating a large, readable directory in Python?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have been assigned a task and I am struggling to get my head around how to go about it (I'm not too experienced at Python, and I can't come up with a way to make it work).

Basically, I have already created a quiz where the user inputs their name and group and then answers the questions, before being given a score.

Now I need to add to the code to allow it to do this:

- depending on the group they inputted, write the information to a certain CSV file
- write the user's name and score to the file

This seems quite straight forward, however I do no know how to go about this. Once I have done this, the extension is that the latest three scores (rather than just one) should be stored in the file for each user.

Additionally, I then need to create a secondary program to read the information in the file. Within this program, the user needs to be able to read the information in three different ways:

- in alphabetical order of the users' names, only showing their highest scores
- showing the users' highest scores, ordered from highest to lowest (with their names)
- showing the users' average scores, ordered from highest to lowest (with their names)

As you can see, this is quite a feat! Any suggestions of how to go about it (general methods, snippets of useful code, etc) are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some snippets like you asked.

**Getting user input**

```
user_input = raw_input("Prompt here: ")  # Python 2.x
user_input = input("Prompt here: ")      # Python 3.x
# user_input will be a string
```

**Reading from a text file**

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

**Writing to a text file**

```
#lines = <some list of lines you've built>

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)  # line should be terminated with newlines (\n)
```

**Reading from a csv file (with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module)**

```
with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

**Writing to a csv file (with the `csv` module)**

```
#rows = <some list of rows you've built, rows should be iterable>

with open(csvfile, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

(If you're using dicts, the [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class may be of interest).

**Using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to build a dictionary where the values are lists**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

# list is some list of lists
for row in list:
    key = row[0]  # These are examples
    val = row[2]  # ''
    d[key].append(val)

# d is now a dictionary, where the values are lists
```

**Getting keys/values/items from dictionaries**

```
#d = <some dictionary>
for k in d:             # Iterate over dictionary keys
    print(k)

for v in d.values():    # Iterate over values
    print(v)

for k,v in d.items():   # Iterate over key,value pairs
    print(k)  # key
    print(v)  # value
```

(In Python 2, a more efficient method would be to use `itervalues()` and `iteritems()`, but we're just keeping it simple).

**Sorting lists**

```
x = [2,4,6,1,3,5]
y = [1,3,5,2,4,6]

x.sort()       # In-place sorting, doesn't return anything
print(x)       # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

z = sorted(y)  # Create a new, sorted list
print(y)       # [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]  (still unsorted)
print(z)       # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Both `sort()` and `sorted()` accept a `reverse` argument that, when True, will sort it in the reverse order (typically this will make it highest to lowest).

For example:

```
x.sort(reverse=True)    # or,
sorted(x, reverse=True)
```

**Finding highest score**

```
scores = [84.5, 90, 80, 82, 99]
high   = max(scores)
print(high)  # 99
```